# Django Multi-Table Inheritance "ptr" On Delete DO_NOTHING

Tags: django, cascade, multi-table-inheritance

Is there a way to apply FK options (db_constraint, on_delete, etc.) to the "_ptr" column automatically created when using multi-table inheritence? I want to stop Django from emulating on delete cascade behavior and have the database perform that natively.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class PersonalArticle(Article):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

PersonalArticle._meta.get_field('article_ptr').rel.on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING
```